Unable to make google sign in in debug mode
In a flutter application, I am using Google Oauth 2.0 client for signing in user. I have created separate client for web, debug and release build. Added sha1 for debug and release build. Debug build was working perfectly and so is release build. All of a sudden, after making some changes (added new client id for release) debug signin is not working at all, though release signin is working just fine. I ensure appropriate sha1 keys are added for both debug and release builds. Getting following error while signing in in debug mode :
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

I tried creating new debug keystore and new sha1, but no change. What is actually making this error?

This sometimes happens because of SHA-1 mismatch. Don't forget to download the google-servce.json from Firebase if you update your SHA-1.
Check this thread, it may help

I am not using firebase, so dont think google-services.json is appropriate here. I assure - my sha1 is correct for respective build.
